# POST multipart/form data to site with checkboxes via python

Tags: python, post, checkbox, multipartform-data

I'm relatively new to python and computers in general. Currently I'm trying to post data to a website, namely http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/featcalc/, and select four checkboxes after uploading a file which contains the data to be analyzed.

So far, this is what I've tried.

```
def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files, data):
    """
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
    Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
    """
    BOUNDARY = '-----------------------------7de18336272e32'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
    L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="seq"')
    L.append('')
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
    L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (files[0], files[1]))
    L.append('Content-Type: text/plain')
    L.append('')
    L.append(data)
    L.append('')
    for (key, value) in fields:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body
```

For this code, data is the file that's been opened, read, and closed, files is the filename and the full filename - ex ('Practice', 'Practice.txt') 
This returned what I thought was a good format. But when I tried to post the encrypted data using urllib2, urllib2 request, and urlopen, I got something that looked like the source code of the results page, but didn't have any of the data that I needed (ie no values). I tried this as well just to see if it would work.

```
files = {'file': ('Practice.txt', open('Practice.txt', 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
r.text
```

The problem is, I think, the page requires that you select a checkbox, and I have no idea how to do that in a post request. I was thinking about trying to use a cgi script next, but I'm literally running out of ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` module will be most useful here, you need to set `data` and `files`

```
files = {'file': ('Practice.txt', open('Practice.txt', 'rb'))}
data = {'amino':'amino', 'aliphatic': 'aliphatic'}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
r.text
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm still having an issue. It doesn't seem to be submitting the data in the file. This is what shows up on wireshark     Boundary: \r\n--41a084d01fce47beaa2327cc74c33513\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part: 
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Bishop/Practice.txt"\r\n\r\n
    Last boundary: \r\n--41a084d01fce47beaa2327cc74c33513--\r\n --It's missing content-type and Line data. Do you have any idea why this is? Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for responding to this post. Someone else posted an answer to this question phrased a little different, and it worked. He used urllib, which followed a similar format to the one above, but the missing piece of code he provided was using 'Sessions = post.sessions(). This got my code to work! Thanks again for responding.

Comment: @Shay - glad you got it figured out, sessions is another important concept.